# Creating new div in existing one

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This code works fine:

```
   pic.forEach(photo => {
        
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = 'photo';
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<img src=${photo.urls.small}>`
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

but I want to nest this newDiv inside exisitng one, so I prepared DIV with class photos.

```
const pic = result.results;
    pic.forEach(photo => {
    const gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('photos');  
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = 'photo';
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<img src=${photo.urls.small}>`
    gallery.appendChild(newDiv);
```

and this one it's not working.

Comment: "it's not working" – what, exactly, is happening? What errors are you seeing? Is nothing happening? Etc.

Comment: "getElementsByClassName" returns an Array, try  iterating and append inside or get the first one in, like this =>  document.getElementsByClassName('photos')[0]

Comment: @Woohaik, Thank you. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getElementsByClassName` will return an `Array`, an  `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>`, that is why, calling directly `appendChild` won't work, you have some options in this case. Loop through all Elements, but it seems to be only one.

```
 const gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('photos')[0];  
 // Both will get only the first Element that matches
 const gallery = document.querySelector('.photos');
```

Now you can append the new Element.